# Swift 3 Beacon Monitoring using CLLocationManager

Tags: swift, background, monitoring, locationmanager, beacon

Here is a shortened version of what I am trying to do with beacon region monitoring using CLLocationManager.

I need to be informed of entry/exit events of multiple (less than 20) regions.

I get consistent location entry events even in the background. I am not getting exit events in the foreground while in the Client View, or in the background.

At one point I did successfully get exit events in the background, but I was not obtaining a variable number of beacon regions to listen to.

Are there any overall convention/logic flaws in this code?

```js
//------------------
/* Client View Controller - Main Profile View */
class ClientVC: UIViewController, ClientVC_Preferences_Protocol, OpenPreferencesProtocol, ClientVCProtocol {

 /* Reference to AppDelegate file where location manager resides */
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
 override func viewDidLoad(){

  // .. Obtain some beacon info - not shown

  for beacon in beacons {
         /* Create a region for each beacon and start monitoring */
         var region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString:beacon.UUID)!, identifier: beacon.Identifier)
         region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = true
         region.notifyOnExit = true
         region.notifyOnEntry = true
         self.appDelegate.locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
     }
 }

 /* Protocol function to alert client when exit event occured */
 func alertClient(businessName:String) {
        
        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertBody = "Did you leave " + businessName + "?"
        UIApplication.shared.presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
        
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: businessName, message: "Did you leave?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes, I Left!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
            UIAlertAction in
         // .. Do some firebase work - not shown
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No, I'm Here!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) {
            UIAlertAction in
            // .. Do some firebase work - not shown
        }
        
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        
        self.present(alertController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
}

//------------------
/* AppDelegate */

/* Protocol connected to Client View Controller */
protocol ClientVCProtocol{
    func alertClient(businessName:String) /* Displays alert to client when exiting the region */
    func reloadTableView() /* Refreshes table view */
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

 /* Delegate for ClientVC Protocol - used to call methods */
 var ClientVCDelegate:ClientVCProtocol?

 /* Instantiate location manager */
 var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

 /* Triggered by entering a region */
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        print("Enter event " + region.identifier)
        // .. Do some firebase work - not shown
 }

 /* Triggered by exiting a region */
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {

  /* Break set on this line to ensure whether or not this function is called */
  print("Exit Attempt") 

  /* Gets business name associated with region and calls protocol function to ClientVC */
  if let beaconRegion = region as? CLBeaconRegion {
            self.getBusinessName(region: region){
                (result: String) in
                print("Exit event " + region.identifier)
                self.ClientVCDelegate?.alertClient(businessName:result)
            }
        }
 }

 /* Runs when application finishes launching - configures location manager */
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {        
        self.fbRef = Database.database().reference()
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: .alert, categories: nil))
        
        /* Not sure how relevent all of these calls are */
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 2000
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        }
        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
      
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Please excuse some of the code indentation, I could not get it to carry over identically.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you only set up the regions to monitor in the `ViewController`, this should really be done in the `AppDelegate` if you want background entry/exit events to fire.

Understand that CoreLocation keeps track of the regions you are monitoring and will auto-launch your app into the background if the region state changes.   It will only fire callbacks, however, if you set up the `CLLocationManager`, regions, and set the delegate in the AppDelegate's  `didFinishLaunching` method.

Comment: How would I listen for beacons that I don't know about until I retrieve a user's data?  Can the application be "relaunched" after signing in and passed this data?

Comment: Apple's documentation leads me to believe when monitoring for a region, it is only listening to UUIDs, majors and minors. When I declare a CLBeaconRegion it requires an identifier and is treating two beacons with the same UUID and different identifiers as two separate regions. How can I listen for a UUID associated region and have different beacons with the same UUID trigger events?

Comment: When testing I create a region to monitor and give it a default identifier "test". When I run the app and introduce a beacon with the same UUID and its own personal identifier, my did exit and did enter region methods get fired once for the region I declared with the "test" identifier, and once for the region that has the beacon's identifier. Shouldn't the exit and entry methods be triggered just once?